# Why did Michael Bay have an insignificantly small role in Coyote Ugly?

Tags: casting, cameo, coyote-ugly

In 2000's film *Coyote Ugly* Michael Bay has a small cameo as a photographer.

[image]

The photograph taken by him was important later in the film but what was the reason for having Michael Bay doing that scene? Michael Bay is not even part of the film production team so having his cameo appears a little odd to me. Is there any story behind this cameo?

Comment: Hmm..none that I can find except he's a friend of Jerry Bruckheimer who produced the movie.

Comment: He likes doing cameos I guess? He did another one around that time in Mystery Men